# how to send message "page will close" from browser to server?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a script (JavaScript) to each html-document, that sends two messages to the server:

- page did open
- page will close (this message contains how long the page was open)

The open-message should be sent when the document is loading (or when it finished loading). This is the easy part.

The close-message should de sent when the document is unloaded from the browser's viewport. <sub>(User clicks on a link that has not target="_blank"; User closes the browser tab/window; User reloads the page; User quits the browser; anything else that makes the page disappear)</sub>

I tried it this way:

```
//================================================================================
//Global Variables
//================================================================================
gl = {}; //container for global variables (1 scalar and 1 function)
gl.start = Math.floor(Date.now()); //timestamp of page-loading


//================================================================================
//function: Send message to server
//================================================================================
gl.sendData = function (action) {
    var message = {
        'href'     : window.location.href,
        'height'   : $(window).height(),
        'width'    : $(window).width(),
        'action'   : action,       //can be 'open' or 'close' (i.e. 'load' and 'unload')
        'rand'     : Math.random() //random number to outwit cache
    };
    if (action == 'close') {
        //how long was the page open? [milliseconds]
        message.duration = Math.floor(Date.now()) - gl.start;
    };
    window.alert(action); //debugging: show if gl.sendData is executed
    $.ajax({
        'url'     : 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/path/to/script.pl',
        'data'    : message,
        'success' : function(){}, //not interested in server's answer
        'error'   : function(){}  //errors will be ignored
    });
};


//================================================================================
//Things to do as soon as page load is complete
//================================================================================
$(document).ready(function(){

    //send message "page did open"
    gl.sendData('open'); 

    //add event-handler to send the message "page will close" when the page is closing
    $(window).on("unload", function() {
        gl.sendData('close'); 
    });
});
```

Sending a message when the page did open is working perfectly fine. But the browser doesn't send the close-message.

I found out this facts:

- "unload" seems to be the correct event. The alert-message pops up when the page is closing.
- "beforeunload" doesn't work because it is not fired (Safari on Mac, when clicking on a link that navigates to another page)
- the ajax-request is sent when the page is loading, so it seems to be ok.
- the ajax-request doesn't send data to the server when the page is closing.

### my Question:

Is there a way to send a massage to the server in the moment when a document is unloaded from the browser?
I want to send the duration of the page beeing displayed to the server. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Depending on how accurate you need it, you could "poll" the server with regular AJAX requests, and the server just saves the last one it gets (overwriting each time)

Comment: I was thinking about polling, but I think, this produces to much useless messages. (The better the accurateness must be, the more junk-traffic you'll get)

Comment: Hence starting with the word "depending" for exactly that reason. Jfriend has given an excellent answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no 100% reliable way to send data to a server when the page is closing that works in all browsers.

With the advent and general availability of webSockets in browsers, there are some who are using a webSocket connection from client to server as a means of tracking this.  When the page is opened, it makes a webSocket (or socket.io) connection to the server.  This connection is kept open for the duration of the page.  When the user leaves the page or closes the browser, the webSocket will get closed by the browser.  The server can then see that the webSocket has been closed and can mark that as the time that the page was closed.

One other possibility that is less efficient than the webSocket connection is for the open webpage to regularly poll the server via Ajax (say every 30 seconds or so to announce that the page is still open).  When the server sees the polling stop, it assumes that page has been closed.

Both of these techniques require regular connectivity with the server in order to do this tracking (e.g. can't be used to track offline usage).